# Concatinate different type arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, integer, byte

suppose, `array1 = ['B',  'G',  'R',  'A']`, array2 is `Uint8Array`, how to concatinate these two arrays ?

I used `var array3 = array1.concat(array2)`, but the result seems wrong , and array3.length is alwalys 5, regardless of content of array2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
var array2 = Array.from(uint8Array);
var array3 = array1.concat(array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your result (`array3`) must also be a `Uint8Array` array.

So, in your example the following should achieve what you're looking for:

```js
const array3 = new Uint8Array([ ...array1, ...array2]);
```

Comment: That array will start with four `0`s, since `"B"`, `"G"`, `"R"`, `"A"` will all get converted to 0 by the [`ToUint8`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-touint8) algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is creating a new array with your four strings followed by the `Uint8Array` as a single element.

[`Array.prototype.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) is an odd beast. If you give it arguments that aren't "[`concat` spreadable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/isConcatSpreadable)" (for instance, things that aren't arrays), it includes those values as simple elements in the array it creates.

Typed arrays are not `concat` spreadable:

```js
const uint8 = Uint8Array.from([3, 4]);
console.log(uint8[Symbol.isConcatSpreadable]); // undefined (and the default is false)
const softArray = [1, 2];
const result = softArray.concat(uint8);
console.log(result.length); // 3
console.log(result[0]); // 1
console.log(result[1]); // 2
console.log(result[2]); // (A Uint8Array containing 3, 4)
```

You could use spread instead of `concat`:

```js
const array1 = ['B',  'G',  'R',  'A'];
const array2 = Uint8Array.from([1, 2, 3]);
const result = [...array1, ...array2];
console.log(result); // ["B", "g", "R", "a", 1, 2, 3]
```